# Continuity of 1/x

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I am confused with what $8(ii)$ wants from me, I answered the first part of this question with help from the question posted here
[Is $f(x)=1/x$ continuous on $(0,\infty)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12462/is-fx-1-x-continuous-on-0-infty)
But the this proves continuity and works for all $\epsilon>0$, so how do I prove it doesn't for $\epsilon=1$??[image]

Comment: The second one is asking you to prove that $x\mapsto \frac 1 x$ is not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general proof for all $\epsilon>0$ shows that specifically for $\epsilon=1$:
$$\forall c\in(0,\infty)\colon \exists\delta>0\colon \forall x\in(0,\infty)\colon |x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<1 .$$
Your task is to show that the slightly rearranged claim
$$\exists\delta>0\colon\forall c\in(0,\infty)\colon  \forall x\in(0,\infty)\colon |x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<1 $$
is *false*.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you take $\delta$ and $c$ is the key! Read carefully the last sentence of (i).