# Examples of Not Uniformly Continuous Function

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity

I'm trying to practice proving that functions are not uniformly continuous using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition, but I'm unable to find much practice with it. Ones that I have tried so far are $x^3$ on $[1,\infty)$, $\frac{1}{x^2-1}$ on $(1,\infty)$, $x^2$ on $[0,\infty)$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1]$.

But I'm still uncomfortable and need more practice with this particular topic.
Does anyone have more examples of simple functions that are not uniformly continuous over a given interval?

Comment: Your last question is confusing.  Which do you want?

Comment: Take your functions and multiply them by 42.

Comment: I recommend you to search for some books that are made for the purpose of providing only counterexamples in real analysis.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The question is edited

Comment: Any unbounded continuous function on $(0,1)$ cannot be uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Michael I suppose that you're correct that those are not uniformly continuous, but the proofs would look exactly the same. I'm looking for something new to try.

Comment: How about $\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229195/ex-sin-x-is-not-uniformly-continuous?rq=1