# What does it mean that a function is uniformly continuous? (Geometrically)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What does it mean that a function is uniformly continuous? (Geometrically)

I have this definition but i dont understand the definition geometrically. Can someone help me to understand this?

Let $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is uniformly continuous if $\forall\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ such that $\forall x,y\in D$ and $\text{|x-y|<}\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

Comment: It means, in some way, that the oscillation of the function is bounded. Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11538/intuition-for-uniform-continuity-of-a-function-on-mathbbr).

Comment: @Masacroso I don't think what you say is always the correct intuition. For example, what is the "oscillation" of $f(x) = x^2$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Bounded first derivative $\implies$ uniformly continuous.  These conditions aren't the same though, as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352321/a-uniformly-continuous-function-such-that-the-derivative-is-not-bounded-and-is-n) is uniformly continuous but not bounded first derivative (additionally, I don't believe that uniform continuity implies $f\in C^1$, but I don't explicitly know that it doesn't).

Comment: @Tom this is the reason what I said "in some way". The oscillation of $f(x)=x^2$, for a distance $\epsilon>0$, is clearly not bounded.

Comment: If a function is continuous but not uniformly continuous then somewhere along the domain, it becomes arbitrarily steep.  The image two points that are nearby in the domain are not nearby.

Comment: I personally think that this is one of those instances where "geometric intuition" is overrated. For instance, a basic fact is that a function $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ is continuous if and only if it is uniformly continuous. I think any "geometric intuition" one could give you about "steepleness" and "slopes" would miserably fail in predicting this.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Can you construct a continuous function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that has a slope which tends to $\infty$ anywhere on the domain? If not, then wouldn't that "predict" the result based on that intuition?

Comment: @Tom Cantor's function is always there, nice and UC on $[0,1]$, with those seemingly very ripid slopes in strategic palces.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli But can you talk about slope anywhere except where it's zero? Don't get me wrong, there are many bizarre looking functions out there which defy "geometric intuition," but my point is that for those that we can picture, should we eschew using them to gain some heuristic?

Comment: @Tom Perhaps it's better to have a handbook of *obstructions* to uniform continuity (examples of what is not UC), rather than an imprecise interpretation of a kind of continuity which often coincides with ordinary continuity. That being said, it's just my opinion (which marks a personal limit).

Comment: By the way, @tom, there are indeed UC differentiable functions $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that $f'([0,\varepsilon])=\Bbb R$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Consider $x^2\sin\frac1{x^2}$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Very good example. Of course, $f'$ is not defined at $0$, but you're right, the slope does tend towards infinity as $x \to 0$. I like your idea of creating a counter example booklet.

Comment: @Tom If you set $f(0)=0$, then $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes, of course. It was implicitly clear that $f(0) =0$ (for continuity). I should have said "continuous" rather than "defined".. my bad!

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Also: $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ for $x \in [0,1]$.